# Get Error while installing TestNG

Tags: eclipse, testng

I have tried to install TestNG in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

During Installation I caught following error and My installation is stopped.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.testng.eclipse,6.5.2.20120616_1545
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.testng.eclipse,6.5.2.20120616_1545
```

Any Idea to resolve this issue??

Comment: please add the way you are installing TestNG. via exacte updatesite or file extraction or something different.

Answer (score 3):

Try the current version of TestNG: **6.7.0.20120825_1316**. 
I just installed and used it in Juno without problems.